# ClickOnce deployment auto update is not working

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployment to check for updates:

1. I have done the settings like in the publish tab, publish URL, and check for updates path, and check for updates before application starts and run application both offline and online.
2. I am getting updates if install the application from local system but, if I install the application from server then it is not checking for updates.

Below is the code that I have used for checking updates. How do I rectify this problem?

```
private void InstallUpdateSyncWithInfo()
{
    UpdateCheckInfo info = null;
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        ApplicationDeployment ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

        try
        {
            info = ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate();
        }
        catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The new version of the application cannot be downloaded at this time. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (InvalidDeploymentException ide)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot check for a new version of the application. The ClickOnce deployment is corrupt. Please redeploy the application and try again. Error: " + ide.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This application cannot be updated. It is likely not a ClickOnce application. Error: " + ioe.Message);
            return;
        }

        if (info.UpdateAvailable)
        {
            Boolean doUpdate = true;

            if (!info.IsUpdateRequired)
            {
                DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("An update is available. Would you like to update the application now?", "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
                if (!(DialogResult.OK == dr))
                {
                    doUpdate = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Display a message that the app MUST reboot. Display the minimum required version.
                MessageBox.Show("This application has detected a mandatory update from your current " +
                    "version to version " + info.MinimumRequiredVersion.ToString() +
                    ". The application will now install the update and restart.",
                    "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            if (doUpdate)
            {
                try
                {
                    ad.Update();
                    MessageBox.Show("The application has been upgraded, and will now restart.");
                    Application.Restart();

                }
                catch (DeploymentDownloadException dde)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the latest version of the application. \n\nPlease check your network connection, or try again later. Error: " + dde);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no updates available");
    }
}
```

**C# project text file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
        <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{1804771A-88C8-49AD-9763-44A296B7EC2B}</ProjectGuid>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>TestUpdate</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>TestUpdate</AssemblyName>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
        <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
        <IsWebBootstrapper>true</IsWebBootstrapper>
        <PublishUrl>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\TestUpdate\</PublishUrl>
        <Install>true</Install>
        <InstallFrom>Web</InstallFrom>
        <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
        <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
        <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
        <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
        <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
        <UpdateRequired>true</UpdateRequired>
        <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
        <InstallUrl>http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/</InstallUrl>
        <UpdateUrl>http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/</UpdateUrl>
        <ProductName>Test UPdate</ProductName>
        <PublisherName>Acharis</PublisherName>
        <SuiteName>www.acharis.com</SuiteName>
        <MinimumRequiredVersion>1.0.0.10</MinimumRequiredVersion>
        <CreateWebPageOnPublish>true</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
        <WebPage>test.html</WebPage>
        <ApplicationRevision>11</ApplicationRevision>
        <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
        <UseApplicationTrust>true</UseApplicationTrust>
        <CreateDesktopShortcut>true</CreateDesktopShortcut>
        <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
        <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>B3D4C4433FA2AC368ACF13B0917D1CFEADFDF92A
        </ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManifestKeyFile>TestUpdate_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
       <Reference Include="System" />
       <Reference Include="System.Core" />
       <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
       <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
       <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
       <Reference Include="System.Data" />
       <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
       <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
       <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
       <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
            <SubType>Form</SubType>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
            <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
            <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
            <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        </Compile>
        <None Include="app.config" />
        <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
            <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </None>
        <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
            <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
        </Compile>
        <None Include="TestUpdate_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
            <Visible>False</Visible>
            <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
            <Install>true</Install>
        </BootstrapperPackage>
        <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
            <Visible>False</Visible>
            <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
            <Install>false</Install>
        </BootstrapperPackage>
        <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
            <Visible>False</Visible>
            <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
            <Install>true</Install>
        </BootstrapperPackage>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
    <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    </Target>
    -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Does Your server request autorization?

Comment: Also please provide url from which You try to update

Comment: Our server is shared UNIX server and the url used for updates is . http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/test.html

Comment: Please try to remove test.html from url, usally URL should target directory with manifest (*.application file)

Comment: Is this is the correct URl:  http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/Application%20Files/TestUpdate_1_0_0_5/TestUpdate.application

Comment: Set InstallationFolderUrl to http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/ and UpdateUrl also to that and then try to redeploy application

Comment: I have tried with this url http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/ for installation and update url but it is not working.And if I run this is url in browser then it is showing error as :                       Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /Clinic/TestUpdate/ on this server. How to set the permissions in code?

Comment: Plese add new version to that directory. Current version is 1.0.0.5, so I wait for higher one.

Comment: It looks like You replaced only HTML file, please publish new version and replae all files in TestUpdate folder with new created by publish files.

Comment: I am updating this folder http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/Application%20Files/TestUpdate_1_0_0_8/ and html file also .

Comment: No, You should update application file in TestUpdate folder and add new folder to ApplicationFiles, which has new version

Comment: I am updating TestUpdate.application file, setup file ,and html page in TestUpdate folder and adding latest version folder folder to the Application files folder.

Comment: It seems that something wrong in your publish settings. Can You please add csproj file text to qyestion?

Comment: I don't understand why current version 1.0.0.10 loads manifest from http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/Application%20Files/TestUpdate_1_0_0_6/TestUpdate.exe.manifest

Comment: I have added the code to the question can please check once and tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: There is no text of csproj file, you should open it with Notepad and copy it here. It is an XML file with project settings.

Comment: I have added csproj file and also i set the permissions in server

Comment: OK. Seems everything is OK with csproj. Please clean your C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\TestUpdate\ and http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/ folder, publish app and copy it to server. We need clean publish with no files anywhere.

Comment: I removed all the files and after publishing copied the files to the server but it is not working. Shall i keep only latest version folder in Application files folder?

Comment: Did you removed all files in publish folder before? I can't understand one thing which is bery strange.

Comment: It looks like clean reinstall and republish solved some problems. Now please publish new version and copy all files to web with replacing existing. And now, You shouldn't keep only last ApplicationFiles folder.

Comment: Yes I removed all the files and published again and now i have only Version 1.0.0.12 folder in Application files folder , test.html ,.application and setup file. And I re install the application again. But still is showing older version form.

Comment: I see messageboxes which is not presented in Your code, so as I can see application can see right files on web. It looks like something wrong with Your update code. Try to set for checking update on before application started.

Comment: I had set the setting as check for updates before starting the application and every time I am changing version to minimum required version so that it asks for mandatory update

Comment: Actually my code is checking for updates in local system and everything is working fine but it is not checking updates if I set the updates check url as server url.

Comment: Can You provide me with your test project?

Comment: I am unable to find how to attach a file to the stack overflow question. If you don't mind can you tell me your Email Id so that i can send you the code please?

Comment: You can send it to stackoverflow@itornotit.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation/update location should be a folder, rather than the test.html file as igofed mentioned.

This next bit is not answering your question, but hopefully will prove useful to you. There is a bug in the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) framework in the method `ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate()` you are calling in your sample, in that if it is called a sufficiently large number of times (in the case of an autonomous application left running indefinitely) it will start to throw exceptions of type `COMException` and `InvalidOperationException`

Now unfortunately I can't recall where I found out about this bug, so I'm unable to give the credit where it's due, but we solved the issue by checking the version number in manifest file and comparing it to the current assembly version.

```
private bool CheckForUpdateAvailable()
{
    Uri updateLocation = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation;

    //Used to use the Clickonce API but we've uncovered a pretty serious bug which results in a COMException and the loss of ability
    //to check for updates. So until this is fixed, we're resorting to a very lo-fi way of checking for an update.

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string manifestFile = webClient.DownloadString(updateLocation);

    //We have some garbage info from the file header, presumably because the file is a .application and not .xml
    //Just start from the start of the first tag
    int startOfXml = manifestFile.IndexOfAny(new[] { '<' });
    manifestFile = manifestFile.Substring(startOfXml);

    Version version;

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    //build the xml from the manifest
    doc.LoadXml(manifestFile);

    XmlNodeList nodesList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("assemblyIdentity");
    if (nodesList == null || nodesList.Count <= 0)
    {
        throw new XmlException("Could not read the xml manifest file, which is required to check if an update is available.");
    }

    XmlNode theNode = nodesList[0];
    version = new Version(theNode.Attributes["version"].Value);

    if (version > ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion)
    {
        // update application
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your update check calling code...

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    bool updateIsAvailable;

    try
    {
        updateIsAvailable = CheckForUpdateAvailable();
    }
    catch
    {
        //not network deployed etc...
    }

    if (updateIsAvailable)
    {
        ad = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;

        if (ad == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ad.Update();
        Application.Restart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uri updateLocation = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation;             The above line is throwing an exception as the application is not installed while trying to run the application from Visual studio.

Comment: It needs to replace your call to `CheckForDetailedUpdates()` - surround it with `if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)` - it's not going to work under the debugger for the exact reason you say.

Comment: Thanks now exception is not coming, but it is not checking for updates. Just now i re installed the application but there is no change it is showing Version 1.0.0.4 even though i installed it from 1.0.0.8

Comment: Is your installation folder url and publish location the same or different?  On the publish page, click the updates button, try checking the "specify a minimum version" and entering your latest version number.

Comment: if each version is being published to folders like http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/Application%20Files/TestUpdate_1_0_0_5/TestUpdate.application - then your installation folder is http://www.acharis.com/Clinic/TestUpdate/
You may need to configure your webserver with permissions to allow access this folder.

Comment: Instead of using ad.CheckForDetailedUpdate().UpdateAvailable, why didn't you just use ad.CheckForupdate?  Does the same .net bug exist in the CheckForUpdate method also?